# Building a EventTriggerBehavior that supports my own customized events

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, windows-runtime

I built my own UserControl (that I consume from a separate assembly) with its own customized events, in the parent project I want to use those events with **Commands** since it's an **MVVM** application, all by using the [Behaviors SDK (XAML) for Visual Studio 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn457340.aspx), as follows :

```
<mediaPlayerControl:PlayerControl>
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ForwardClicked">
                    <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnForwardClicked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</mediaPlayerControl:PlayerControl>
```

The problem is that the EventTriggerBehavior supports only some specific events as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn469361.aspx), hence the commands I'm using on my events don't fire, now, what I want to do is, to build behaviors that provide the same experience, and that support my own event: I want them to look similar to this :

```
<mediaPlayerControl:PlayerControl>
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:ExtensionsEventTriggerBehavior EventName="ForwardClicked">
                    <core:ExtensionsInvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnForwardClicked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</mediaPlayerControl:PlayerControl>
```

I've read many articles about implementing such behaviors, but I couldn't get it clear for me since it's the first time I deal with them this way, I would like if you show me how to do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you would normaly not add the behavior inside the UserControls XAML Page, you would add the Behavior on the XAML Page where you use the UserControl, so i think you will need something like this:

You can simply add a public event of type `EventHandler` e.g. "ForwardButtonClicked" to your Codebehind of your UserControl:

```
public event EventHandler ForwardButtonClicked;
```

Then you must add a EventHandler Method too, to get your event fired when the button is clicked on the view. So you would add a eventhandlermethod inside the constructor of your usercontrol:

```
public PlayerControl()
{
  this.InitializeComponent();
  _forwardButton.Click += this.ForwardButtonClickedEventHandler;
}
```

The Eventhandler would look like:

```
private void ForwardButtonClickedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
  if(this.ForwardButtonClicked != null)
  {
    this.ForwardButtonClicked.Invoke(sender, new EventArgs());
  } 
}
```

Then you can add your UserControl to a XAML Page and add a EventTriggerBehavior for the ForwardButtonClicked Event of your UserControl.
Since there is no support for Custom RoutedEvents in WinRT you may use a default clicked RoutedEventHandler instead of a normal C# EventHandler because you lack bubbleing and tunneling of events. But i don't know if this is working, i did not try it because i did not need bubbleing or tunneling yet.
If someone has a better solution, i would much appreciate to read about it.